# CRM 2011: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred. referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am getting the following error message when I execute this query. If I remove the second where clause, query works fine.

**Code**

```
(from cl in context.CreateQuery<ContractDetail>()
  join a in context.CreateQuery<Account>()
      on cl.CustomerId.Id equals a.AccountId
  where cl.StateCode.Value == 0
  where cl.new_SupportedBy == a.Name
  select cl).ToList();
```

**Error**

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe`

``` Additional information: variable '<>h__TransparentIdentifier0' of type '<>f__AnonymousType0``2[ConsoleApplication1.ContractDetail,ConsoleApplication1.Account]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined ```

**UPDATE**

Try to hardcode the value in where clause as following and both time it worked. Can't understand what is the issue.

Firstly tried as:

```
where cl.new_SupportedBy == "abc"
```

Secondly:

```
where a.Name == "abc"
```

**Exception Thrown By Linq Pad**

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToValue(Expression exp, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToConditionValue(Expression exp, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereCondition(BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, Boolean negate)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(String parameterName, BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, Boolean negate)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereBoolean(String parameterName, Expression exp, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, BinaryExpression parent, Boolean negate)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetQueryExpression(Expression expression, Boolean& throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean& throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection& projection, NavigationSource& source, List`1& linkLookups)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at UserQuery.RunUserAuthoredQuery() in c:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad\_nmuxfnrq\query_lnnofb.cs:line 34
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: and if you remove the first where clause? did you try also to invert the order of the where clauses?

Comment: already tried. Tried to hardcode cl.new_suportedby and a.name separately. Both time it worked.

Comment: there is a simple way to check if it is a problem with the CRM LINQ provider, do a ToList() after each CreateQuery, and check if it works

Comment: Its Taking ages now. I am still waiting  :)

Comment: ToList() is making it too slow, got exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in

Comment: where .... && ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted the problem as below:

```
var contractLines = (from cl in context.CreateQuery<ContractDetail>()
  join a in context.CreateQuery<Account>()
  on cl.CustomerId.Id equals a.AccountId                                 
  where cl.StateCode.Value == 0
  select new {cl, a}).ToList();

var collection = new EntityCollection();

foreach (var line in contractLines)
{
    if (line.a.Name == line.cl.dbc_SupportedBy)
    {
        collection.Entities.Add(line.cl);
    }
}
```

I understand, it is not a perfect solution. But as this application is only one time run, so I don't mind if it performs slow. But I am still curious to know why the error occurred, so I will keep this question open.

**Update**

Kept it open for more than six months without any reply. So I am closing it now, as this workaround worked for me and also closing for the sake of my answer acceptancy percentage :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  where cl.new_SupportedBy == a.Name  is the problem

You can't write a CRM LINQ query wherein the where clause that contains a predicate that compares attributes; even if those attributes are defined on the same entity instance.

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d510944-c46f-4698-a6aa-c3ed5f76dc77/freaky-linq-issues-with-joins?forum=crmdevelopment